# Adding to favorites and counting in Ajax form in the header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have no idea how to use Ajax in WordPress, Added a favorite button to posts, And using Elementor's counter widget, I added a favorite counter to the header and called its value from the database. Now the add to favorites button and the number of favorites counter work properly, the only problem I have is that when the add to favorites or remove from favorites button is clicked, the counter works in ajax.

This is the HTML code of the counter :

```
<span class="elementor-counter-number" data-duration="2000" data-to-value="6" data-from-value="0">6</span>
```

This button is add to favorites and remove from favorites :

```
<span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
    <span class="dce-add-to-favorite-text-remove elementor-button-text" data-favoritecount="-1">remove favorite</span>
    <span class="dce-add-to-favorite-text-add elementor-button-text">add favorite</span>
</span>
```

The number of favorites added by the user is also stored in this part of the database :

[image]

Also, I made a popup, when the user clicks on the counter icon, all his favorite content will be listed, how can this part be ajaxed, when the user clicks on the add to favorites button, it will be ajaxed in the popup. pop-up appears or if the user clicks on the button to remove from favorites either in the pop-up or in the blog, it will be removed from the pop-up using Ajax.

```
<div class="dce-view-results-wrapper">
   <div class="dce-view-results">
      <div class="dce-view-row elementor-row dce-view-grid  dce-flex dce-view-archive">
         <div class="item-page dce-view-col dce-view-single-wrapper dce-view-grid-element   dce-view-element dce-view-element-1961 elementor-column elementor-col-100">
            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated dce-view-single">
               <div class="elementor-widget-wrap dce-block">
                  <div data-elementor-type="loop" data-elementor-id="7007" data-post-id="1961" data-obj-id="1961" class="elementor elementor-7007 dce-elementor-post-1961 elementor-location-popup">
                     <div class="elementor-section-wrap">
                        <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-16afa1b elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="16afa1b" data-element_type="section">
                           <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                              <div class="elementor-row">
                                 <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-04a1c74" data-id="04a1c74" data-element_type="column">
                                    <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                       <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                                          <section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-4cfdb51 elementor-section-content-middle elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="4cfdb51" data-element_type="section">
                                             <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                                                <div class="elementor-row">
                                                   <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-d8785bc" data-id="d8785bc" data-element_type="column">
                                                      <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                                         <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                                                            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-4b8fe1f elementor-widget elementor-widget-theme-post-featured-image elementor-widget-image" data-id="4b8fe1f" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="theme-post-featured-image.default">
                                                               <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                                                  <div class="elementor-image">
                                                                     <img width="2560" height="2560" src="http://localhost/ii/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/featured-image-of-article-number-9.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-image-6093" alt="مقاله شماره 9" loading="lazy" srcset="http://localhost/ii/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/featured-image-of-article-number-9.jpg 2560w, http://localhost/ii/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/featured-image-of-article-number-9-300x300.jpg 300w, http://localhost/ii/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/featured-image-of-article-number-9-100x100.jpg 100w, http://localhost/ii/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/featured-image-of-article-number-9-600x600.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 365px) 365px, (max-width: 487px) 487px, (max-width: 767px) 728px, (max-width: 1024px) 487px, (min-width: 1025px) 365px">                                                        
                                                                  </div>
                                                               </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                         </div>
                                                      </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-6129ec7" data-id="6129ec7" data-element_type="column">
                                                      <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                                         <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                                                            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-8cb93e6 elementor-widget elementor-widget-theme-post-title elementor-page-title elementor-widget-heading" data-id="8cb93e6" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="theme-post-title.default">
                                                               <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                                                  <h1 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"></h1>
                                                               </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                         </div>
                                                      </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </section>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </section>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="item-page dce-view-col dce-view-single-wrapper dce-view-grid-element   dce-view-element dce-view-element-5504 elementor-column elementor-col-100">
            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated dce-view-single">
               <div class="elementor-widget-wrap dce-block">
                  <div data-elementor-type="loop" data-elementor-id="7007" data-post-id="5504" data-obj-id="5504" class="elementor elementor-7007 dce-elementor-post-5504 elementor-location-popup">
                     <div class="elementor-section-wrap">
                        <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-16afa1b elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="16afa1b" data-element_type="section">
                           <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                              <div class="elementor-row">
                                 <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-04a1c74" data-id="04a1c74" data-element_type="column">
                                    <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                       <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                                          <section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-4cfdb51 elementor-section-content-middle elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="4cfdb51" data-element_type="section">
                                             <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                                                <div class="elementor-row">
                                                   <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-d8785bc" data-id="d8785bc" data-element_type="column">
                                                      <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                                         <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                                                            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-4b8fe1f elementor-widget elementor-widget-theme-post-featured-image elementor-widget-image" data-id="4b8fe1f" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="theme-post-featured-image.default">
                                                               <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                                                  <div class="elementor-image">
                                                                     <img width="2560" height="2560" src="http://localhost/ii/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/featured-image-of-product-number-9.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full wp-image-6056" alt="محصول شماره 9" loading="lazy" srcset="http://localhost/ii/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/featured-image-of-product-number-9.jpg 2560w, http://localhost/ii/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/featured-image-of-product-number-9-300x300.jpg 300w, http://localhost/ii/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/featured-image-of-product-number-9-100x100.jpg 100w, http://localhost/ii/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/featured-image-of-product-number-9-600x600.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 365px) 365px, (max-width: 487px) 487px, (max-width: 767px) 728px, (max-width: 1024px) 487px, (min-width: 1025px) 365px">                                                        
                                                                  </div>
                                                               </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                         </div>
                                                      </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-50 elementor-inner-column elementor-element elementor-element-6129ec7" data-id="6129ec7" data-element_type="column">
                                                      <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                                         <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                                                            <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-8cb93e6 elementor-widget elementor-widget-theme-post-title elementor-page-title elementor-widget-heading" data-id="8cb93e6" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="theme-post-title.default">
                                                               <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                                                  <h1 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"></h1>
                                                               </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                         </div>
                                                      </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </section>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </section>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```